# Multiple applications using the same DLLs

Tags: .net, dll

We have a large volume of small .NET applications (many hundreds). Many of these applications utilize the same DLLs. What is the best way to deploy these applications while cleanly handling the DLLs?

Our current solution uses a "dashboard" application that can organize and launch the other applications. It takes the executable from one folder, the DLL from another folder, and then copies both of them to a different folder, from which the program is then launched. This actually works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner/simpler way of doing it?

One suggestion was to create a separate folder for each application. This keeps things nice and organized, but creates the obvious problem that each application has to have its own separate copy of the DLL.

Another suggestion was to keep all of the applications in one giant folder along with the DLLs. This solves the DLL issue, but you end up with hundreds of executables, config files, DLLs, etc, all smushed together in one folder. I can't actually pinpoint why this would be a bad thing, other than it just seems messy and unorganized.

Is there a more proper/accepted way of handling this situation, or do we just have to cobble something together and run with it?

Comment: I find more messy to have many folders for every single executable all of which belong to the same application solution. And keep track of which executable uses a particular dll to distribuite a new version correctly? It seems a lot of unnecessary troubles waiting to happen

Comment: For native dlls, just set up your PATH properly, that's all there is to it. Want to launch app X and dlls are in folder Z? Make a launcher (can be as simple as a .bat file) which adds Z to the PATH, then start X. For managed dlls: similar, via app.config or setting assembly search path in code.

Comment: I’m not sure why you think it’s a problem to have multiple copies of the same DLL. That is the approach that results in the cleanest dependency graph. Disk space is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

### Every application in one giant folder

I think this solution is quite good. It is very simple. However it has one big problem. What if you update one dll to a new version? You will have to update every single application - so you end up with some sort of dll hell.

### GAC

You could put the dlls in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache). GAC supports deploying multiple versions of the same dll. On the other hand the deployment will be much more difficult.